# How do i add if else with break and continue in nested for loop, the outcome should be that there are spaces between rows

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1;i<14;i++){
     for (int j=1;j<=i;j++){
      System.out.print(6 *j+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
   }
  }
```

This is the code that i need to add break and continue on.

```
6 

6 12 

6 12 18 

6 12 18 24 

6 12 18 24 30 

6 12 18 24 30 36 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 66 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 66 72 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 66 72 78
```

The outcome should be like this, Im just starting java so simplifiying helps and im still learning

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by adding a new line to your print statement as follow:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(6 * j + " ");
            }
            System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
```

I've used the `System.lineSeparator()` to ensure that we will break the line independently on the operation system we're running - so for Linux for example it would be `\n` while on windows it would be `\r\n`

Alternatively, you can simply call the `System.out.println()` twice, and it will do the same...

You can see that running this code will result in the following output as expected:

```
6 

6 12 

6 12 18 

6 12 18 24 

6 12 18 24 30 

6 12 18 24 30 36 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 66 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 66 72 

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60 66 72 78
```

If it's important to you to avoid the last empty line you can add an if-statement to the outer loop and check the index

Comment: Why not simply a second `System.out.println()`?

Comment: I though that I added this as alternative option, but it seems like I didn't save, will add this as well :)